# Remove Unity Icon when 'Unlock from Launcher' does not appear

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, uninstall

I recently installed the LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 meta package via the Ubuntu Software Center. This does not contain LibreOffice Base, so I installed it separately via the Ubuntu Software Center as well.

Doing so created two icons on my Unity dock:  one for the main program and one for Base. I cannot remove the icon for Base. Whenever I right click on the icon, it gives me three options:  New Database (this is normal and works as expected), a blank space that does nothing when clicked, and Lock to Launcher which does nothing when clicked.

How can I remove this icon for Base from the launcher? I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to add a picture of exactly what I see, but I'm considered a new user. The system wouldn't let me, and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to upload it somewhere else and link to it.

Comment: Completely restarting my machine fixed it. It's still a bug that needs to be fixed, but I found the answer to this problem is a full restart.